# More than 1 directory Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Hi im trying to redirect more than 1 directory to root. This is my code. Is this correct?

```
Redirect 301 ^/(sub1|sub2|sub3)(.*) http://domain.com
```

The above is not working. I have to use the long way instead.

```
Redirect 301 /sub1 http://domain.com
Redirect 301 /sub2 http://domain.com
Redirect 301 /sub3 http://domain.com
```

Comment: thanks for reply anubhava. I thought it was correct too but it's not redirecting. I have to use the long way and it works. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` that supports regular expressions:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(sub1|sub2|sub3) http://domain.com
```